# Finding the minimum of two numbers

Tags: xml, xsd

For this flowchart on finding the minimum of 2 numbers:

[image]

I've created XML for this flowchart:

```
<start>
    <InOut>
      <in>  a </in>
      <in>  b </in>
      <out> min </out>
    </InOut>
    <calc>
        <ins> a=3 </ins>
        <ins> b=5 </ins>
        <ins> min=a </ins>
    </calc>    
    <con gurd="min>b"  type="if">
        <calc>
            <ins>min=b</ins>
        </calc>
    </con>
    <con gurd="min>b" type="else">
        <calc>
            <ins>min=a</ins>
        </calc>
    </con>
</start>
```

But I don't think it's not good XML coding.  What are your suggests for improving this?

Comment: Does it still work properly?

Comment: Wait, what's the significance of the C++ code?

Comment: @Jamal c++ is sample and not important for me
i want create xml for code like that

Comment: Why are you trying to make it look like a completely different language?  Why not the most concise in the particular language you're using?  The least you could do is replace the C++ code with pseudocode.

Comment: i have flowchart for detect minimum in 2 number i write c++ code replace flowchart image i edit this code and replace flowchart with c++ code @Jamal

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are some confusing aspects to your XML, and some practices that you may end up appreciating.....

### Technical

Your XML is valid, but it does not follow best practices. The XML:

> ```
>    <con gurd="min>b"  type="if">
> ```

This should be written:

```
    <con gurd="min&gt;b"  type="if">
```

Even though your XML is valid, the `>` in the attribute value can lead to confusion. Even the XML Syntax parser here on Stack Exchange is failing to parse that part right....

### Naming

XML is by nature relatively verbose. You are already 'paying' for that, so you may as well use it to your advantage. `con` should be `condition`, `ins` should be ..... `instruction` ? What is `gurd` ?

Additionally, you should be consistent in cases. `InOut` should be `inputoutput` or something. Mixing cases for XML tag names is a problem. I recommend making it all lowercase. I would actually call it 'interface', and have 'input' and 'output' as child elements.

### Functional

When you use XML, you need a parser. There is always a balance between what you parse, and what you let the parser parse. The 'text' component in the XML elements are technically called `PCDATA` (Parsed Character Data). The XML Parser will Parse that data looking for more XML. That's all it does. Your actual data has things like: `min=a` Is your application manually parsing that content as well? If it is, you should probably make your text content attribute values instead.

Additionally, the white-space in your element text is scattered all over the place. Consider:

> ```
> <calc>
>     <ins> a=3 </ins>
>     <ins> b=5 </ins>
>     <ins> min=a </ins>
> </calc>    
> <con gurd="min>b"  type="if">
>     <calc>
>         <ins>min=b</ins>
>     </calc>
> </con>
> ```

In your first `<ins>` elements you have space surrounding the text. In your later `<ins>` there is no space.

Is the space important? If it is, you should either use attributes, or set `xml:space="preserve"` on your XML.

### Update

FYI, I ran your XML through xmllint and it output your XML as:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<start>
  <InOut>
    <in>  a </in>
    <in>  b </in>
    <out> min </out>
  </InOut>
  <calc>
    <ins> a=3 </ins>
    <ins> b=5 </ins>
    <ins> min=a </ins>
  </calc>
  <con gurd="min&gt;b" type="if">
    <calc>
      <ins>min=b</ins>
    </calc>
  </con>
  <con gurd="min&gt;b" type="else">
    <calc>
      <ins>min=a</ins>
    </calc>
  </con>
</start>
```

[`xmllint --format your.xml`](http://www.sunsite.ualberta.ca/Documentation/Misc/libxml2-2.4.10/man/xmllint.1.html) is a fantastic commandline tool that validates and reformats your XML to be consistent. I recommend it to anyone using XML that has access to Linux

Comment: *that has access to Linux* ... how exactly would one go about not having access to Linux?